# Creating scaled bitmap

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap

I need to test a simple task. I want to create scaled bitmap by setting `postScale` to the `Matrix` and using it in the creation, here's a code:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postScale(5.0f, 5.0f);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapSrc, 500, 500, 50, 50, matrix, true);
```

I thought this code supposed to crop 50x50 bitmap from the source scaled in 5 times, but when i'm using this bitmap to show the result in `ImageView`

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

The scaling doesn't seem to work and i'm getting 50x50 bitmap from original source bitmap(without scaling).

I think i'm missing something, but i can't quite figure out what. Any help highly appreciated

*Edit:* I've also tried to set last parameter to false and it didn't help, but if i'm using `postRotate` in matrix i'm getting rotated bitmap

Comment: You should use the method Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap, int, int, boolean)

Also check this if your image is big http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: change `matrix.postScale(5.0f, 5.0f);` to `matrix.postScale(5.0f, 2.0f);` and you will see the difference... anyway, just use `Log.d` to log the value of `bitmap.getWidth()` and `bitmap.getHeight()` and watch the logcat

Answer (score 1):

Android contains the function `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()`...
You can use this as follows:

```
public Bitmap getScaledBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, float scale) {
    Integer originalHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
    Integer originalWidth = bitmap.getWidth();

    Integer requiredHeight = Math.round(originalHeight * scale);
    Integer requiredWidth = Math.round(originalWidth * scale);

    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, requiredWidth, requiredHeight, true);
}
```

You can checkout this for other relevant functions [here](https://github.com/BijoySingh/BasicAndroidProject/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/birdlabs/basicproject/util/ImageManager.java).

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the scaling happens too late and the crop area is out of bounds because of it. Did you try it with preScale instead of postScale?

If that does not work, you can try using coordinates within the small bitmap first, like this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapSrc, 100, 100, 10, 10, matrix, true);
```